# getting casino links on my woocommerce site

Tags: spam, hacked

i am getting various casino links on my site, i have searched everywhere in the files in my database, but i can't locate the issue, these links come and go they mostly appear in the header and the footer.
After clicking on the link they linked to:

```
http://my/sitehollywood-casino-columbus-jobs/
```

I have attached a screenshot. Your help is most appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your site is almost definitely compromised. Doing your own cleanup may not be worth the time and effort because reinfection is likely if you miss a single infected file. 
At this point I recommend to my clients that they get professional help. You may be able to get more details from a site scan by Sucuri. They have a free remote scan for virus infection.
[Site scan by Sucuri](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/)

Comment: i already scanned it with sucuri (No Malware Detected by External Scan)

Answer (score 0):

Either rebuild your WordPress site from scratch. Ditch plugins that aren't updated for quite a while and don't paste and copy any content without proper inspection and sanitization.

Or; **ask a professional** for help. who will probably rebuild the most part of your site from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix it yourself, I'd do this:

change the database password (ask the googles for help on this process)

- change your FTP passwords
- change your email passwords
- change your hosting passwords
- use strong passwords throughout
- use the Dashboard, Update to reinstall WP 4.8
- also update any plugins or themes noted there
- check the .htaccess file for changes (make a new one)
- reinstall all themes (download files from theme home and upload to the proper folder via FTP or cPanel)
- do the same for all plugins
- remove/delete any plugins/themes you don't need or use
- look for any posts/pages you didn't create; delete them

Long-term, keep everything updated.  This is a bit of work, but can be done with some knowledge (and you can also ask the googles how to do most things).  If you aren't comfortable doing all that, then find a consultant that will help you. It will cost, as the whole process is time-consuming.

Another option is to start from scratch - kill the old site completely (delete database and files) and reinstall everything. But that's not usually possible with most established sites.

This hack/attack can be recovered from...I've done it before. It just takes a bit of time and knowledge to do it. If you have content that must be saved, it will be a bit more complex, but still doable.

Good luck!

**Added**

And since you have a WooCommerce site, go through each product listing and remove anything that doesn't belong (could be some code inserted in a bogus product).

Comment: i did everything you mentioned, but still i am getting the links when i check my site using google cache.

Comment: There's something hiding in your site code. Reinstalling everything (WP/themes/plugins), checking for files (sort by date to find something out of place), checking htaccess, changing every single password associated with the site and host (FTP, email, hosting), disabling/clearning cache, check your local computer, and every product (since you have WooCommerce) should be the way to find it. If you can't find it, you might need to get some pro help to help you find the issue.